# How to deserialize a [System.Serializable] struct with a dictionary property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a struct that has a [System.Serializable] tag that looks something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public struct User 
{
    public string name;
}
```

I want to add an experiments property that is a `Dictionary<string, string>`. I can't make it another Serializable struct because it changes dynamically (on the backend) and the keys also contain `-`s.

However doing the following makes it so `experiments` is always deserialized as `null`. I've also tried using an `IDictionary` type.

```
[Serializable]
public struct User 
{
    public string name;
    public Dictionary<string, string> experiments;
}
```

I've confirmed that the server is sending down this json:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "experiments": {
        "experiment-3532": "control"
    }
}
```

FWIW, this is how I'm using the struct

```
public IEnumerator GetUser(Action<User> callback, Action<string> errorCallback)
    {
        string url = "https://myurl.com/myurl/"; // fake endpoint

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Version", Application.version);

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.error == null)
            callback(JsonUtility.FromJson<User>(request.downloadHandler.text));
        else
            errorCallback("Uh oh! Network error");

        request.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in [FromJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) docs:

> Fields of the object must have types supported by the serializer.
> [..]Only plain classes and structures are supported

Dictionary is not supported. Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity/36244111#36244111).
I find myself comfortable with [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) when working with JSON. It is one of the most used libraries, it could be your go to.

Comment: thanks. i converted it to use JSON.Net. that was super annoying!